# LDAP path - where to find

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to search for some GPO object using DirectoryServices. The first step is to bind to LDAP. I have an active directory lab environment where I created a virtual machine as a Domain Controller. In order to bind to this LDAP, I obviously need to determine the path to use in DirectoryEntry class. How can I find that path to use, is it somewhere within properties of AD domain services?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What you typically do is just point your LDAP bind request at the IP address of the domain controller. In fact, if the machine you are on is in the domain of the domain controller you don't even need to do that, it is the default LDAP bind target. To experiment and get an idea of the AD structure you should download and play around with the AD Explorer program: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found this GPMC Class library, may try this instead of DirectoryServices?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee840126(v=vs.85).aspx

Seems you can get the GPO using samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee862406(v=vs.85).aspx

**I never use that before.** So try on your own risk :)